# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in sbt scala 2.11 IntelliJ IDEA sbt 1.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I have executed Scala code in IntelliJ IDEA for spark.streaming.kafka, where I am using scala version 2.11, sbt 1.0 and spark version 2.0.1

I am trying to send message through Kafka producer and trying to fetch in spark cluster I have executed the below command in spark cluster:

```
bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0- 
10_2.11:2.0.1 --class "KafkaWordCount" --master 
spark://bluedata5.bdlocal:7077 jars/sskafka_2.11-0.1.jar localhost:2080 
sds_test
```

Code:
KafkaWordCount.scala

[image]

Build.sbt

[image]

Error:
Output 1

[image]

Output 2

[image]

Kindly do help me to solve the error

Comment: Please copy-paste code and stacktraces and format it using `Ctrl + K` instead of posting images.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is clear enough which says

> > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : KafkaWordCount

All you have to do is to provide *full padkage path to KafkaWordCount class* i.e. `kafspa.KafkaWordCount`

So your `spark-submit` command should be

```
bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.0.1 --class kafspa.KafkaWordCount --master spark://bluedata5.bdlocal:7077 jars/sskafka_2.11-0.1.jar localhost:2080 sds_test
```